# Simple update query is taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `CurrentStatus` in my database (subscription database in a merge replication)
Columns are `StatusID {Primary Key + Clustered Index}, StatusName, StatusDate, UserID,CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy, AllowDelete,AllowUpdate`

CurrentStatus table as 26000 rows

updates and deletes on this table are suddenly taking too much time say 1 min 30 sec to even 5 min.

Below query is taking over a minute to execute.

```
update StatusMaster set StatusName='OK' where StatusID = 22
```

There were previously 5 indexes on table (even then the query used to execute fast.)
Now as the update/delete queries are not executing, i have deleted all indexes and kept only two indexes 
1) Clustered Index on StatusID
2) Replication index on rowguid column which is an unique nonclustered index created by replication automatically.

Whn i take backup and restore the database, the queries on same table run fine.

One more thing is that i have complex query running every 2 mins from around 20 machines on server.

What is causing this queries to consume so much time to execute?

[Click here for Execution plan](http://narliagripada.com/exe.html)

Comment: is the replication running when you did these tests?
If the DB is a subscriber, you actually shouldn't be deleting\updating it's data, should you?

Comment: @Diego yes replication is running + its merge replication so insert update can work on any of subscriber and publisher

Comment: @AamodThakur Let's deal with one query at a time, not 6 of them! And I can't read the text in the image, please provide a link to the image instead.

Comment: @RedFilter please check  - http://narliagripada.com/exe.html  for images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend that you update your statistics via the [UPDATE STATISTICS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) command, e.g.:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS StatusMaster
```

Comment: its has helped to reduce the execution time but still taking 20 odd seconds

Comment: sometimes it takes 1 sec and sometimes over 15 seconds, memory consumption on server is 2.5 gb out of 4 gb and processor utilization is 45%

Comment: It is possible that the `StatusID` column has low cardinality so that it is doing a table scan. What does your execution plan say?

Comment: Hit `Ctrl-M` and then run your query. You'll see an additional tab in SSMS for your results called `Execution Plan`.

Comment: and which values should i look for?

Comment: Probably best to post a picture of the execution plan.

Comment: i have attached the images, can you check?

Comment: In some cases Update statistics works, but sometimes it doesnt work, i have to restart the SQL server service

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My UPDATE command used to take 28 minutes and it takes only 2 seconds now. Amazing!!!

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of inserts, deletes, updates, etc., you table can get fragmented and your indexes may not be optimized.  I would suggest that you re-index and update statistics.

When you take a backup and restore it, I believe you are accomplishing the same thing as the re-index and update of statistics would do.

You should probably schedule maintenance like this on a recurring basis to maintain performance.

Comment: i have rebuilded the indexes and updated the statistics, but still facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Last time when some simple queries took abnormal amount of time [in our little company], this was caused by RAID array corruption in [fortunately non-production] SQL server.

Comment: how can i find if my RAID array is corrupted?

Comment: Ask person, who administers that computer, where SQL server is located. You need to check windows eventlogs and if present, RAID controller status logs. I don't say that this is your case - I have no experience with replication and can't say, what effect this can cause; I just hinted that sometimes strange delays are caused by hardware problems.

Comment: As this table is in replication, and i am getting error on 4 to 5 servers i dont think it will be a RAID issue

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but i may help someone.
We had similar problem right now, found out there was trigger "after update" causing simple update to take too long.